# Vertically centered div

Tags: html, css

I realize there are lots of examples out there, and I am working from one but cannot seem to get it to function properly.

Here's what I've got currently:

```
<div id="w">
    <div id="iw">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#w {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
}
#iw {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#iw a img {
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -o-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/zjWaz/)

Basically I want to vertically and horizontally centre the `iw` container.

The idea I had read about is the wrapper container is `display: table;` and the inner content is `display: table-cell;` and then you can use the vertical-alignment from the table.  Great, now how do I make the table 100% height of the page? best I can do is a fixed height, which (without the use of JS) will not help me be exactly vertically centred.

Comment: Please don't **just** post a fiddle link to your code; always include it *within* the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following CSS instead:

```
html,body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#w {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#iw {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#iw a img {
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -o-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

See this in an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjWaz/1/

Comment: Beat me to it. when using this technique for centering elements vertically, height:100% must be applied to all containing elements. Way to go, Ujjwal! +1

Comment: the important things to note here are: After testing; the height property is not needed for the `iw` element. Table-cells by default will fill/assume height and width of their parent table. And I was also only applying the `height/width` properties to the `body` and not `html` ***(which is key)*** +1 check.

Answer (score 1):

if you know width and height easier would be to position iw absolute, top: 50%; left: 50% and set negative margin half height and width (lets say width/height are 200px that way `margin: -100px 0 0 -100px` )

Answer (score 1):

Check this Css

```
body {
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
 }
#w {
display:table;
width: 100%;
}
#iw {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:-100px;
margin-top:-50px;
}
#iw a img {
-moz-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
-o-box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
box-shadow:0 1em 1em #444;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Also check Updated Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zjWaz/4/

Hope you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

you dont need any js or like something, just apply the style as a table:
display:table and table row with 100%.
look up for more info here: 
http://linuxandfriends.com/2009/04/04/how-to-style-div-elements-as-tables/

Or better, you can do it with a div fixed